# Using a base class in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Using SignalR, I have the following Hub classes below and here I want to collect shared methods in a Base Hub class:

**HubBase**

```
public class HubBase : Hub
{
    public readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        if (!_connections.GetConnections(name).Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
        {
            _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        }
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }


    public void SendChatMessage(string who, string message)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
        {
            Clients.Client(connectionId).addChatMessage(name + ": " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

**StockHub**

```
public class StockHub : HubBase
{
    private static IHubContext context = GlobalHost
       .ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockHub>();

    public static void SendStockData(object data) {
        context.Clients.All.sendStockData(data);
    }
}
```

**StockHub**

```
public class ChatHub : HubBase
{
    private static IHubContext context = GlobalHost
       .ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();

    public static void SendMessage(string message) {
        context.Clients.All.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1- As the HubBase is inherited by Stock and Chat hub classes, I think all the connected clients to one of those methods will be added connected users in the HubBase. So, when I broadcast data to the clients who connected to StockHub, I will also broadcast data to the other clients who connected to ChatHub. Is that true?

2- How can I fix this problem without defining all the connection classes in Stock and Chat hub instead of Base hub (HubBase)?

As it is not logical to define these shared methods for all of the hub classes, I need to discriminate the user who connect to StockHub. How can I do this?

3- In addition to that, I am wondering what if I do  not use none of these connection methods and any base class (define each hub classes separately with no relation), and use `Clients.All` method in order to broadcast data, in this case will the broadcast only goes **only** to the clients who connected my hub? If so, for this scenario there is no need to use connection methods (assuming that I broadcast to all of the clients connected to StockHub). Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignalR allows messages to be sent to all connections associated with a specific user, as well as to named groups of connections.

Groups in SignalR : it is manages the Users and Groups for you which associated with Hub

```
public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
}

public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has left the group {groupName}.");
}
```

read more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Dear Nemi, I have also lol at some of your useful articles regarding to SignalR for the last 2-3 weeks, thanks a lot for your helps :)

Comment: In this case, I think I can use HubBase class and add the methods above to that base class. And then whenever a user connect to the hub, I will add this user to the specific group according to the type of different broadcast (refresh dashboard, send message). Is that true?

Comment: What's do you think about my 3rd question?

Comment: yes, you have to manage different groups as per your requirements.

Comment: Ans to 3rd question : Client.All broadcast message to all connected clients including you as well if your are also connected. Client.Other method also there if you want to sent message to all user excluding you.

Comment: I have look at the page you suggested. In this case I think I need to add all the connected users to the related group. So, what is the best place to do this? I think I call AddToGroup() method in OnConnected() method by passing group name. Also call RemoveFromGroup() method from OnDisconnected() method. Is that true?

Comment: Many thanks for your helps, voted up and marked as answer :)

Comment: On the other hand there are normal and async calls regarding to all of the hub methods. So, which one do you suggest? Should I use async methods for connections and the others in the Hub class? Or some of them async, the others normal?

Comment: You should use async methods.

Comment: Do you mean all of the Hub methods (OnConnected() ..., AddToGroup(), RemoveFromGroup(), SendMessage(), SendMessageToGroups()) ? What about the custom methods in the hub? Should they also be async as well?

Comment: And what is the reason for this? Could you pls clarify a little bit more? Thanks...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196903/discussion-between-hexadecimal-and-nemi-chand).